# How to install Ubuntu Builder on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I've seen several videos on youtube that after downloading Ubuntu Builder it dosn't starts.

Please someone tell me how to install it...

Comment: What's Ubuntu builder?

Comment: @handuel Ubuntu Builder is a simple tool to create your own distribution of Ubuntu

Comment: Ah OK. I'll go and look into how it's set up.

Comment: Try this one http://handytutorial.com/install-ubuntu-builder-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-using-ppa/

Answer (score 5):

Open a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) and run these commands  (it supports Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:f-muriana/ubuntu-builder
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-builder
```

If you have issues after installation, go here: https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/issues/list?can=1&q=&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+Milestone+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles. There are a lot issues presented, some of them fixed.

Comment: looks like its discontinued https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder/+announcement/12508

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of Ubuntu builder from here:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder.

Assuming your file is in Download directory, open terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>,  navigate to that directory with `cd Downloads` and type this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i install ubuntu-builder_2.4.0-gb3-1_all.deb
```

Comment: `apt-get` knows to install the most recent version of the package after you have runned `sudo apt-get update`. So, I do not understand why you should download the latest version...

Comment: Is it wrong? I shared a link on the comment which shows how to install from ppa using apt-get. I think this is an alternative solution. That's all.

Comment: Is ok, nothing wrong.